# Socket.io compile error

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm, node-gyp

This is the error im getting..

```
> ws@0.4.25 install C:\Users\Darryl\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\Darryl\.node-gyp\0.8.7\deps\uv\include\uv.h(55): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\Darryl\node_modules\socket.io\nod
t.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
Project : warning PRJ0018: The following environment variables were not found: [C:\Users\Darryl\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
```

What makes it an issue is that the binding.sln dir/file does exist ( I have visual studio express 2012 installed)

I also have python installed but, it seems to ignore that.

Kinda lost on how to get around this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had resolved the issue by specifying the visual studio version while installing the socket.io package.

You can try using:

npm install socket.io --msvs_version=2012